# How can I do a weight selection in admin page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I saw that many modules create a weight selection tool (I mean the interface where you can drag and drop). I want to do it as well in my module, but I couldn't find any information about this.... Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look onto these links

1- http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/09/drupal-drag-and-drop-tables-in-custom-modules

2- http://drupal.org/node/1224318   "this link has a sample code".

this is a link for a ready to use example http://www.ulterius.nl/sites/default/files/download/tabledrag-6.x-1.tgz

Comment: Sure :) . Contact me in case you need more help anytime .